# Center google maps vue component

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

[image]

I have a vue/nuxt google maps component that looks like:

```
<template>
  <GmapMap
  :center="{lat:10, lng:10}"
  :zoom="7"
  map-type-id="terrain"
  style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
>
  <!-- <GmapMarker
    :key="index"
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    :clickable="true"
    :draggable="true"
    @click="center=m.position"
  /> -->
</GmapMap>

</template>


<script>


export default {
  // name:'myMap'

}

</script>


<style>
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;;

</style>
```

The map is not centered (please see screenshot). How can I center it?

Comment: have you tried `margin: 0 auto` directly in the style attribute of GmapMap? `style="width: 500px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto` centering technique only works on block level elements.

So give your component `display: block;`

```css
div, span {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 200px; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>working</div>
<span>not working</span>
<span style="display:block">working</span>
```

Alternatively, you could simply wrap it inside an element with:

- `text-align: center;`
- or `display: flex; justify-content: center;`

Comment: sorry, don't know much about css. what does "So give your component display: block;" mean

Comment: It means what I did for the 2nd span in my answer. I applied `display: block` to its `style` (you can also do it via CSS). By default, `<span>` elements have a `display` value of `inline`. Yet, because I've given it `block`, you can see it works on second `<span>`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm using vuetify so I ended up using v-container and v-flex box as well